# python join "large" file

Tags: python, string, list, memory, join

In python I have read in a file into a list using `file.readlines()` , later on after some logic, I would like to put it back together in a string using `fileString = ''.join(file)`, for some reason, even without a `print` function, it prints the fileString out to the console up to a certain point, then it just stops. It does not run the rest of the program which is not useful for me.

Why does join do this, how do I perhaps pre-allocate how much memory I would like my list/string to use so that it does not stop. Or some other solution too.

Thank you

Comment: sorry, `readlines()` is used. makes a list. I am just using generic names here but I do not use system names within my actual code

Comment: You shouldn't use system names in example code either - it might put people on the wrong track as to where the error lies.

Comment: I do not understand your question: "after some logic..." why are still dealing with the original file descriptor `file`? Haven't you read in the content to some variable (`str` or `list`) and why don't you start from there? If it is a `list`, then there is no point `join`ing the whole list if you want to stop "at a certain point". You should use a loop to iterate your list until where you want it to stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File is your file pointer in memory. When you attempt to join on it, you don't actually have a string to work with.

How about this?

```
with open(file, 'rb') as myfile:
    strings = myfile.readlines()

# do your stuff to strings
filestring = ''.join(strings)
```

Note that strings is a list of lines like this:

> ['my line\n', 'my other line!\n']

And as such, a large file will require quite a bit of memory. You may be better served by building a mini filter.

Comment: Actually, unless you have already read the file, you *can* use `''.join(myfile)`; it returns a string the same way `myfile.read()` would have done.

Comment: false alarm, it is the plistLib that is causing an error :(  `IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long:`

Comment: But never use this, please. "There should be one obvious way to do it", and if you need to slurp a file into memory at once, use `.read()` :)

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker If I ever have to do something as horrifying as "hey you can use a pointer(couple of bytes) as if it were one gigantic blob of text! But only in this special case" then I'd throw python away and hunt Guido down for ruining my favorite language ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider what you are going to do with the resulting string. If you just want to write the contents back to a file, there is no need to join the parts first, you can use `file.writelines(strings)` directly.

Comment: super! this helped a lot